# How to construct the Wigner-Seitz cell for a two-atom basis, like, e.g., a hexagonal lattice from Graphene?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, graphene

I tried to construct the Wigner-Seitz cell with its perpendicular lines as explained in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Seitz_cell) for a hexagonal (honeycomb) lattice.

[image: hexagonal lattice with: Wigner-Seitz cell in green, construction lines in blue and primitive unit cell in gray]

(hexagonal lattice [[1](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Honeycomb_lattice_-_hexagonal_lattice_with_a_two-atom_basis.svg)] with: Wigner-Seitz cell in green, sketched construction lines in blue and primitive unit cell in gray)

I know that hexagonal has a two-atom-based primitive unit cell. On the other hand, the Wigner-Seitz cell should be unique. So, what am I doing wrong during the construction?
Is it just impossible to construct a Wigner-Seitz cell for a hexagonal lattice as the shape that I constructed is not area-filling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your construction is wrong; you would have gotten the hexagon if you did it correctly.

You have picked one green atom as the centre. Your blue lines from this green atom should only be drawn to neighbouring green atoms. Your perpendicular bisectors of these lines are not sufficiently perpendicular nor bisecting.

If you did it correctly, 3 red atoms will be on 3 vertices of the hexagon. 3 of thirds, making up exactly one red atom and one green atom inside each hexagonal Wigner-Seitz cell.