# How to construct the Wigner-Seitz cell if you don't know it is a two-atom basis?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, graphene

Assuming we don't know that e.g., Graphene has a two-atom basis. How does the Wigner-Seitz Construction lead me to a two-atomic base?

[image: Construction of a two atom base: green and a one atom base in yellow]
So, assuming we do not distinguish jet between the green and red atoms in the picture: 
What is wrong with the construction of the yellow triangle as a Wigner-Seitz cell? 
Why do I need a two atoms Wigner-Seitz cell? 
Are the grey Rhombus and the green Hexagon the same but related to different base starting points?

The construction of the Wigner-Seitz cell is described e.g. in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Seitz_cell) or can be in set theory written as {r∈ℝ:|r-R<sub>0</sub>|<|r-R<sub>n</sub>|} with n the other cells excluding n=0 and R<sub>0</sub> the origin.

Comment: Disclosure: 
1. I know it looks like I am asking multiple questions but still they are related/similar.
2. I already tried to ask this question [hier](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/764294/how-to-construct-the-wigner-seitz-cell-for-a-two-atom-basis-like-e-g-a-hexag) but actually asked something different. 

Feel free to correct me or give me a hin if this is the wrong approach.

Comment: The triangular shape cannot be the unit cell (primitive or not). Can you fill the (2D here) space with it by translations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll attempt to answer all the questions.

A unit cell of the 2D structure needs to be able to tile the plane by translating the origin along the basis vectors. Try moving the yellow triangle along any of its sides. Without rotating it you won't be able to recreate the surface. To be exact, your cell only contains one green atom and no red atoms. You'll find that your cell perfectly tiles half the plane, only including the green atoms. This is why the triangle is not sufficient and why you need both atoms included.

The gray rhombus cell in this image is not the Wiegner-Seitz cell, it's only a primitive cell. Look at the definition in the Wikipedia article you linked:

> The Wigner–Seitz cell around a lattice point is defined as the locus of points in space that are closer to that lattice point than to any of the other lattice points

Without the color distinction you would end up with the triangle, but you would see that this does not tile and then you try again.
This is also Step where you realize that you need a two atomic base.

To get a Wiegner-Seitz cell you first need to define where your lattice points are. This can be ambiguous but needs to fulfil certain conditions as explained earlier and it's easiest to exploit the symmetry of the structure. The image you have drawn over defined the lattice points in the middle of the empty hexagons and not at the atoms. This is why they drew their vectors as they did. Your green hexagon defines the green atoms as lattice points. Try to draw two vectors between other green atoms and you'll see how you'll get something similar.

Once you've defined your lattice points (green atoms) you shall draw equidistant lines to the nearest points (nearest green atoms) and then cut them in half. As you've done, which resulted in the green triangle. The Yellow Marked area is the Wiegner-Seitz cell and for clarification all green Atoms got a black circle:
[image: Green Atom Centered Hexagon]

If you instead put the lattice points in the middle of the empty hexagons and draw lines to the nearest other hexagon centers, then cut these in half, you'll end up with the same hexagon but it lies at a different relative position to the atoms. You can find this example in this picture:
[image: Offcentered Hexagon]